# Hypothetical Non-Null Language - How would a Linked List be implemented?

Tags: null, linked-list, language-agnostic, programming-languages, non-nullable

Suppose you are writing in a programming language where `null` simply doesn't exist. It either uses empty objects or throws a `ObjectNonexistentException` or something similar.

Now you want to implement a linked list. But:

- You can't point to `null` to end the list.
- If you point to an empty object to denote the end of the list, it will initialize its own pointer with another empty object. This will go on indefinitely until memory is full.

How do you go about it? What features would that hypothetical programming language have to support to make a linked list possible without using `null` in any form?

Comment: A lot of real-world (non-hypotheical) languages that doesn't have a null also have a native list type. Some languages call them list, some languages call them arrays. They're almost always implemented as some sort of linked list underneath (ropes, b-trees etc). Languages without such array/list types need linked lists to emulate them. Therefore most languages without null types never need to implement linked lists because you can use the native list/array type instead.

Comment: @slebetman: When you say native lists/arrays that are implemented as linked lists...does implementation still mean the contiguous memory kind of array? Could you maybe expand on this in a separate answer?

Comment: Most high level languages don't implement arrays/lists as contiguous memory. Rather, they're implemented as linked lists of elements/cells/cons/words at the machine level. Contiguous memory objects are still available but they're usually called strings and in most languages they're immutable values (though not necessarily immutable variables). Though even that is not always the case. Some languages have started using more optimized data structures for strings (ropes is one popular example).

Comment: Should I make this an answer? I mean "you never need linked lists" doesn't sound like a direct answer to your question but it is how real-world languages respond to this problem.

Comment: I think this would be an useful answer, even if it doesn't directly relate to my question. If you don't mind, adding some examples would be great, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be using something that is equivalent to the Maybe type.  It has either the value Just x, where x in this case is the next node in the list, or Nothing.  The Maybe monad is best demonstrated in Haskell.

http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads

Comment: You don't even need the "monad" part. Just having two subtypes of values `None` and `Some(x)` is enough.

Comment: Well the monadic part allows you to operate on the list neatly and uniformly as any other Maybe type, but you are right. It is not necessary at all.

Comment: I don't really know anything about monads, `None` or `Some`, but I'm assuming you don't need to do anything equivalent to a null check in order to avoid crashing the program?

Comment: No, you wouldn't.  For instance, Maybe has two possible values: Just x or Nothing.  If the language supports algebraic data types/pattern matching, it is **very** easy to check which value the variable has.  Now, if you are pattern matching and don't include a case for all possibilites, your program will crash.  However, you can usually set a pattern as a catch-all (much like default with switch statements).

Answer (score 2):

One approach you could use would be to introduce a dummy cell whose next pointer points back to itself. That dummy cell, which we could call Nil, doesn't require any null pointers. Every linked list can then use a pointer to Nil instead of a pointer to null to denote the list end.

Your question seems to suggest that this wouldn't work because in creating the Nil cell, the next pointer would default to pointing to a new cell, which would point to a new cell ad infinitum. I'm not sure that would necessarily have to be true, since you could imagine that the programming language would give you some way to initialize the pointer other than automatically creating a new object for it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be for the end-of-list object to point to itself. This would require the language to support that ability, of course, but such a thing is not unusual.

If the language has object oriented features, then you could define an abstract type or interface to use as the list item, with implementations that either point to the next item in the list or don't.

```
abstract class ListItem {}
class ListItemNormal : ListItem { ListItem next; }
class ListItemEnd : ListItem { }
```

Some languages have Dependent Types where the value of one field can determine whether another field exists or not. In that case, a null value could be simulated with a separate Boolean variable.